# Creation of several clickable 3D models on the site

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a 3D model of a city with 4 buildings and I would like to make them interactive. When you hover your mouse over a building, text will appear on top of that building, and when you click, a modal window will open. And so with every building. I just started studying the Three.js and would appreciate your advice. Should I add each building separately to make them clickable? And is it possible to create such an interactive with 3D objects?

I read that Raycaster is used for similar purposes. but I don’t fully understand how I can apply this to my project

Answer (score 2):

First, create a Raycaster:

```
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster()
```

And then, put this inside your render function (the looped one):

```
raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera)
```

For those who don't know, `camera` is your camera obviously, and `mouse` should be something like this:

```
const mouse = new THREE.Vector2()

window.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
    mouse.x = event.clientX / sizes.width * 2 - 1
    mouse.y = - (event.clientY / sizes.height) * 2 + 1
})
```

And for those who don't know; Raycaster casts a ray, and it's used when you want to know what objects intersect with it. So that's why you use it to apply your desired mouse events to the objects/meshes/geometries.

And don't forget to add this line of code as well:

```
let currentIntersect = null
```

Then, put this inside your render function (the looped one):

```
const modelsToTest = [model1, model2, model3, model4]
const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(modelsToTest)

if(intersects.length){
    if(currentIntersect === null){
        //do stuff
        console.log('mouse enter event occured!')
    }
    currentIntersect = intersects[0]
}
else{
    if(currentIntersect){
        //do stuff
        console.log('mouse leave event occured!')
    }
    currentIntersect = null
}
```

Congrats, now you simulate-ish the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event!

The next mission is to add `click` event. It's simple, as you can put this block of code somewhere in your script:

```
window.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(currentIntersect){
        switch(currentIntersect.object)
        {
            case model1:
                // do stuff when model 1 clicked!
                break

            case model2:
                // do stuff when model 2 clicked!
                break

            case model3:
                // do stuff when model 3 clicked!
                break

            case model4:
                // do stuff when model 4 clicked!
                break
        }
    }
})
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer! Sorry if this is a stupid question, but... Do I understand correctly that if I want different text and information when I hover and click on a models, do I need to write own const modelsToTest and const intersects  for each model?

Comment: Don't mention it! Not for each model, you just need `intersects` for all four models, and the same for `modelsToTest`. Once you do it, you can check out my code to add mouse events ;) Please test my code, and let me know here!